# Return a JSON based on a sent variable via POST

Tags: php, json, curl, post

I have the following code that builds a url with the email parameter.
After that, I receive the JSON values of id and username available on the json.php page and assign them to my $_SESSIONS.

login.php

```
    require "conn.php";
    $url=('http://example.com/json.php');
    $str = file_get_contents($url ."?email=".$email);
    $json = json_decode($str, true);        
    $_SESSION['id']=$json[0]['id'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$json[0]['username'];
    header('Location: main.php');
```

json.php

```
    require "conn.php";
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $mysql_qry = "SELECT id, username FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = ($conn->query($mysql_qry));
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
```

My system works well this way, but I would like to use POST methods instead of GET. I have tried in many ways but so far I have not succeeded.

If anyone can help me I appreciate it very much.

Comment: ```$str=curl_init($url);curl_setopt_array($str,[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,CURLOPT_POST=>1,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>["email"=>$email]]);$str=curl_exec($ch);``` + `    $email = $_GET['email'];`  - also you're vulnerable to SQL injection, check https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php  - try```    $mysql_qry = "SELECT id, username FROM usertable WHERE email = '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'";```

Comment: @hanshenrik Dont you think that would be more useful written as an Answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @hanshenrik Also Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: @hanshenrik thanks for the help! I did exactly that you posted but i got the following error: Warning: curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in $str=curl_exec($ch);

Comment: @Rodrigo my bad, i meant ```$str=curl_exec($str);```   try that

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe but he's using the MySQLi interface, i don't like the MySQLi interface and hardly know how to use it, and he's doing several things wrong, so.. couldn't be arsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_get_contents() isn't suited for POST requests, and use GET requests by default, hence why all your data lands in $_GET instead of $_POST. (notably, it's *possible* to, dare i say, trick file_get_contents() into doing a POST request, but, it's a stupid idea, you shouldn't do it.)

when you need POST requests, use curl.

while i'm at it, want to mention that `$str = file_get_contents($url ."?email=".$email);` needs urlencoding, it should be `$str = file_get_contents($url ."?email=".urlencode($email));`

but when you want to do a POST request, use curl, so instead of:

```
$str = file_get_contents($url ."?email=".urlencode($email));
```

do:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        "email" => $email
    ]
]);

$str = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now it will land in $_POST['email'] instead of $_GET['email']

another thing, you're vulnerable to SQL injection here

```
    $mysql_qry = "SELECT id, username FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
```

to fix that, you should port $conn to PDO, there's a nice guide here for that: https://web.archive.org/web/20190330214051/http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers